# HtmlAgilityPack Erorr while open xml file

Tags: c#, xml, html-agility-pack

I think my problem is simple, but i can't undertand it.
I have a xml file, looks like this:

```
<categorys>
   <category name="">
        <link>some_link</link>
    </category>
</categorys>
```

and i open it like so:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("categorys.xml");
```

HtmlDocument class read this xml like `<link/>some_link`. What's wrong?

For example, my file here: https://yadi.sk/d/ftS2_daS3LNHdy

Answer (score 0):

As the name says, HTMLAgilityPack is meant for reading HTML documents, not XML documents (by the chance some XML documents may work if it is mostly html like).

You need to use `XmlDocument` class to handle that.